# Allow custom role to see specific section in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, roles, capability

I am trying to allow the custom role `bbp_moderator` to view the `Users` Section from wordpress backend, but for some reason is not working. i can see the roles via the `$wp_roles` global variable and the capability `edit_users` had been added the the `bbp_moderator` role.

```
function add_capablilities_to_mod() {
    $role = get_role('bbp_moderator');
    $role->add_cap('edit_users');
}

function add_user_table_to_moderator() {
    global $wp_roles;
    //
    //var_dump(current_user_can( 'bbp_moderator' )); -> true
    if ( current_user_can( 'bbp_moderator' ) ) {
        add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'add_capablilities_to_mod' );
    }
}
add_action('init', 'add_user_table_to_moderator');
```

Comment: Anyone please. Tried quite a lot of things and re-checked the documentation. This should have let me see the users section as a bbp_moderator.

Comment: Just noticed again capability `edit_users` had not been added.